# Get assembly location in CoreCLR

Tags: coreclr

Under CoreCLR, I cannot get the assembly location like I was able to under .NET Framework.

It appears that Location is not a member of Assembly and that the static methods on Assembly, such as GetExecutingAssembly, are also gone.

What is the preferred method to get the assembly directory, or any directory information about my running program?

I've tried CoreCLR versions:
1.0.0-beta5 coreclr x64
1.0.0-beta6 coreclr x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `1.0.0-beta6` I assume you are talking about DNX.

You can use [IApplicationEnvironment](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions/IApplicationEnvironment.cs). That will give you the name and base path of the application.

`Assembly.Location` would be tricky because you can have code that's compiled on the fly so the assembly is not in a location that you might expect.

Comment: I setup a CoreCLR console app and found the IApplicationEnvironment interface, but I couldn't find an implementation of it. Is there a something else that gives me an implementation of that interface?

Comment: Just pass it as argument to the constructor of the `Program.cs` class. It will be injected by DI like here: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling/Program.cs#L20

Comment: That worked. Thank you! :) I wonder what else can be injected by the framework.